# C# groupbox visibility in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I Googled around but seems my problem happens when two gropboxes are overlapping, in my case they are not overlapping!
Problem is that the `Visible` property of groupbox doesn't work. what am I trying to do is that groupbox1 is visible when program starts and groupbox2 is not, by clicking on a button it should goes invisible and groupbox2 should appear, clicking the same button this action should be done vice versa.

here is my code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (groupBox2.Visible == false)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = false;
            groupBox2.Visible = true;
        }
        if (groupBox1.Visible == false)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
            groupBox2.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that after the first `if`-statement, it immediately checks if `groupBox1.Visible` is `false`, which it always will be. It then proceeds to flip it back.

Change the `if` to an `else`, or at least and `else if` and your code will work.

Comment: Ops! thank you so much, this happen when you code like hell in 3 am ;)

Comment: No problem. It happens to everyone. You could also simplify this to: `bool swap = groupBox2.Visible; groupBox1.Visible = swap; groupBox2.Visible = ! swap;` without the `if`-statements. I will say, that for readability, the `if`s are likely better, but the above code is not exactly unreadable.